# Liquibase trying to insert data into a column using incorrect data type

Tags: liquibase, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to wire up liquibase to be used with Snowflake.  I got it to build and start up.  It creates the DatabaseChangeLog and DatabaseChangeLogLock tables.  But when trying to insert data into the DatabaseChangeLog table I get the following error:

```
WARNING 10/4/18 5:13 PM: liquibase: Unknown database: Snowflake
Unexpected error running Liquibase: SQL compilation error:
Expression type does not match column data type, expecting TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) but got TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9) for column DATEEXECUTED
```

I found the code to convert DATETIME to TIMESTAMP_NTZ, but this is moot as Snowflake has now added the DATETIME data type.  How am I supposed to get the metadata to load into this table if Liquibase is trying to load it into a different data type?

I am open to all suggestions, but I am not a java programmer, so it will not be an easy go if I have to create java programs to correct this issue.

Comment: Don't know about Liquibase, but perhaps you can work around the problem by setting TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING to TIMESTAMP_LTZ , or CLIENT_TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING to TIMESTAMP_NTZ. See https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#timestamp-type-mapping for more info. You can set it e.g. on your account level. If it helps, please let us know.

Comment: I tried every variation and none of them work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, someone with Java development experience will need to make changes to either Liquibase or in a Liquibase extension to support the snowflake DBMS.

Comment: I found some open source code that is "supposed" to do this, but I am not sure I hooking it up correctly....where would I place the jar file that is supposed to manipulate the timestamp field and how do I ensure that the process is using that file?

Comment: If you point me to the code you are referring to I might be able to help. Generally, if you put a jar file in the `LIQUIBASE_HOME/lib` directory, Liquibase will see it and use it.

Comment: I got it to work with doing things a little differently.  I fond a thread that said to set the defaultSchema=<schema>.  Then I let Liquibase create the table with the incorrect data type for dateexecuted in the databasechangelog table.  After that I dropped and recreated the table with the correct data type for dateexecuted.  I fired my instance back up and it ran without issues.  It didn't try to recreate the table again.  It loaded just fine and now I can deploy into Snowflake.

Comment: I will continue to work through things right now, but I still need to get a translator for Snowflake.  I believe that the database code is the problem and not Liquibase.  Liquibase issues a command to insert into the table CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.  Snowflake is interpreting this to be TIMESTAMP_LTZ and not TIMESTAMP_NTZ like I told the database to interpret.  So for now this will work just fine and I can create a schema start up script to build the tables out manually then I do not have to worry about further failures.

Comment: Snowflake extension: https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/spaces/CONTRIB/pages/113372651/Snowflake+extension

Comment: yes I know of this, but this is not the problem.  All this does is allow the DATETIME data type to be interpreted properly, Snowflake has already incorporated this into their database.

Comment: I can confirm that the snowflake liquibase extension doesn't solve this problem, even though the documentation suggests otherwise: https://github.com/CDKGlobal/liquibase-snowflake#currentdatetimefunction . I was able to solve the problem same way as @WallyShoot , by dropping the column `DATEEXECUTED` and adding it back with correct type `TIMESTAMP_LTZ`. Followup liquibase commands work.

Comment: I have been using liquibase to deploy my Snowflake without issues for over a year now.  It is really quite awesome and versatile.

Answer (score 0):

Until there is a fix on Snowflake/liquibase side for this, I worked around this issue by introducing a change set that should be the first one executed by liquibase:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="user">
        <comment>Fix liquibase type mismatch</comment>
        <sql>
            <!--Due to snowflake and liquibase datetime type mismatch-->
            ALTER TABLE "DATABASECHANGELOG" DROP COLUMN "DATEEXECUTED";
            ALTER TABLE "DATABASECHANGELOG" ADD COLUMN "DATEEXECUTED" TIMESTAMP_LTZ;
        </sql>
        <rollback>
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```